# Match the exact class in html <div> tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to scrape information from a website.

Relevant code:

```
page_url = https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=sponsored&radius=1500&postcode=&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&make=Vauxhall&model=Corsa&year-from=2008&year-to=2010&minimum-mileage=82376&maximum-mileage=123564&page=2

page = urllib2.urlopen(page_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Now I just want to print every price on the page that is within `<div class="vehicle-price"></div>` tags, for example:

```
<div class="vehicle-price" data-label="search appearance click">\xa34,400</div>
```

So I use:

```
for i in soup.select('div.vehicle-price'):
    print (i.string)
```

This works fine EXCEPT there are some `<div>` tags like this:

```
<div class="vehicle-price physical-stock-mrrp" data-label="search 
appearance click new car">
```

And the code still prints what is within these tags too.

How can I tell Beautiful Soup that I only want the tag contents when `class="vehicle-price"` and not when `class="vehicle-price other-things-too"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:not() CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to exclude the other class

```
.vehicle-price:not(.physical-stock-mrrp)
```

BeautifulSoup 4.7.1

You can chain with `Or` syntax for example. Example chaining would be `.vehicle-price:not(.physical-stock-mrrp), .vehicle-price:not(.somethingElse)`. Other selector ideas might include passing attribute = value selector and use ^,*,$ operators to specify substrings to match in the attribute values. Apparently, thanks to @facelessuser, you can also pass selector lists to `:not`.

Comment: Thank you. There is sometimes text other than 'physical-stock-mrrp' - so is there some way that I can do something like .vehicle-price:not(anything-else)?

Comment: So, yes you can pass other things inside if that is what you meant. But not a list. You have to chain with Or.

Comment: You can use selector lists in :not. That is currently implemented.

Comment: @facelessuser   ooohh.....that is good to know. Thanks. Have updated and need to do some reading up it seems.

Answer (score 3):

You can [use a custom function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to match all `div` with only `vehicle-price` class.

```
html="""
<div class="vehicle-price" data-label="search appearance click">\xa34,400</div>
<div class="vehicle-price physical-stock-mrrp" data-label="search
appearance click new car">
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Tag
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
def my_match_function(elem):
 if isinstance(elem,Tag) and elem.name=='div' and ''.join(elem.attrs['class'])=='vehicle-price':
     return True
print(soup.find_all(my_match_function))
```

Output

```
[<div class="vehicle-price" data-label="search appearance click">£4,400</div>]
```